# How to show list properly in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to show item list ul li. I have two types of input likes array.ul li and I must must support both types. If I give first array type list item should be work or If i give array 2 list item should be work now array 2 is working but If I give array 1 type it's not working.

How to change my code to support both types?

Array 1:

```
myArray = ["fgtr1",ghyt2","juki3"];
```

Array 2:

```
myArray = [
{
  mode: 'enable', name: 'ashk'
},
{
  mode: 'disable', name: 'qwer'
}
];
```

Comment: In your first array, you don't have an object. It is just an array with 3 strings. The second array contains two objects. You have to make some if-statement to check if it is objects and then render it. You rarely use same component for these two, as they usually have different use cases. 

My recommendation is to create two different.

Comment: @SebastianBerglönn  :  I am new in angular2..Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: This isn't really an issue with Angular, it is more a javascript question. `public get myArrayInput(): Array<any> {
    // If the items inside the array is NOT object, it means it is something else.
    return this._myArrayInput.map(item => {
      if (typeof item !== 'object') {
        return {
          action: item,
          name: item
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
  }`. Thats how I solved it

Comment: @SebastianBerglönn: I am confusing..Please edit my stackblitz and send me.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmwyjk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Here you have URL. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ug1tfj

Comment: But If i use array1 i am getting like this:<span class="Test 1"></span>  Test 1 is wrong css class name rite?So how can i avoid that?

Comment: And pullet points i could not use suppose  If i use array 1

Comment: Well that is the issue. If you dont have the key, you wont be able to get the class. You could change the `key: 'disable'`, but you need to create some default.

Comment: mmm..getting confusion..How we can create default key? If i giving array 1 do not have item.action but why i am getting that value as a class? Can you edit the stackblitz?

Comment: @SebastianBerglönn If you have the time, maybe consider writing an answer as you seem to have solved the problem at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the items inside the array are two different types. One is an object with keys and values, and one is strings.

So you have to make some kind of if-statement to check if it is an object or not.

`const array1 = ['Test 1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];`

```
const array2 = [
  {
    action: 'disable',
    name: 'Test1'
  },
  {
    action: 'enable',
    name: 'Test2'
  },
];
```

```js
public get myArrayInput(): Array<any> { 
    // If the items inside the array is NOT object, it means it is something else. 
    return this._myArrayInput.map(item => { 
      if (typeof item !== 'object') { 
        return { 
          action: item, 
          name: item 
        };
      }
      return item; 
    });
  }
```

If the array is not an object, it will create an object and set the key `action` and `name` to the value `item`.

However, you might want to set a default value to the action, so you could change it from

```
return {
  action: item,
  name: item
};
```

TO

```
return {
   action: 'disable',
   name: item
};
```